# postgreSQL recursive - find all cycles that contain multiple employees and different jobs in other companies

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

To be more specific, I am supposed to use recursive psql to solve a problem. We have this:

- Person A is the CEO of company X and chairman in company Y.
- Person B is the CEO of company Y and director in company Z.
- Person C is the CEO of company Z and deputy chairman in in company X.

Using recursive SQL, find all cycles that contain 3, 4 or 5 employees, where each employee has the role of CEO in one company and either director, deputy chairman or chairman in the next cycle.

[image: Here is a visual representation of the graph]

```
-- This is the table in mind:
CREATE TABLE info (
company text
job text
employee text
primary key (company, job, employee)
);

-- Desired result
Cycle     Employee     Job        Company
-------------------------------------------
1         Jonathan     CEO        DillCO
1         Joseph       CEO        Joestar
2         Jonathan     Chairman   Joestar
2         Joseph       Director   DillCO
```

I am not particularily great at SQL, but I'm learning. You can interpret this problem they way you want to, and it doesn't need to be exactly like my desired output (as it is my interpretation of it).

Here are some sample data you can insert into the table:

```
insert into info values('Bolk', 'CEO', 'Stein Hald');
insert into info values('Forsk', 'Chairman', 'Stein Hald')
insert into info values('Bolk', 'Chairman', 'Guro Dale');
insert into info values('Bolk', 'Director', 'Rolf Numme');
insert into info values('Bonn', 'CEO', 'Hauk Storm');
insert into info values('Bonn', 'Chairman', 'Live Brog');
insert into info values('Bonn', 'Director', 'Tor Fjeld');
insert into info values('Braga', 'CEO', 'Truls Lyche');
insert into info values('Hiro', 'Deputy chairman', 'Rolf Numme');
insert into info values('Hafn', 'Chairman', 'Hauk Storm');
```

Here is what I have:

```
-- so far, finds all CEOs recursively in the first cycle
WITH RECURSIVE cycle (emp, job, comp, cyclenr) AS (
SELECT si.employee, si.job, si.company, 1
FROM info si 
UNION ALL
SELECT c.emp, c.job, c.comp, c.cyclenr+1
FROM cycle c
JOIN info c2 on c.emp = c2.employee
WHERE cyclenr < 1
)
SELECT * FROM cycle
WHERE job = 'CEO';
```

This will only find all CEOs in the first cycle, but I'm having trouble with the rest.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and your desired results? I don't understand given the `info` table you shared here how this would need to be recursive so some sample data and desired results would really help out here.

Comment: @JNevill will do

Comment: @novicekiddo5131 . . . Sample data in a tabular format would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sure

Comment: @novicekiddo5131 . . . Your sample data has no cycles so it is not a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea.  Filter down to just the CEOs.  Then generate all combinations of them and check for cycles.

For a cycle of 3, this looks like:

```
with ec as (
      select distinct employee, company
      from info
      where job = 'CEO'
     )
select *
from ec ec1 join
     ec ec2
     on ec1.employee <> ec2.employee  join
     ec ec3
     on ec3.employee not in (ec1.employee, ec2.employee)
where exists (select 1
              from info i
              where i.employee = ec2.employee and i.company = ec1.company and i.job in ('Chairman', 'Director')
             ) and

       exists (select 1
              from info i
              where i.employee = ec3.employee and i.company = ec2.company and i.job in ('Chairman', 'Director')
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from info i
              where i.employee = ec1.employee and i.company = ec3.company and i.job in ('Chairman', 'Director')
             ) ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c51b99fc271bc02002c8a8fef752e51c) is an example.